# Alchemy Websocket Sub with Filter on Arbitrum Returns No Messages

Tags: websocket, alchemy

The following sub with filter is not resulting in an error and no messages are received for newly mined txns:

```
'{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["alchemy_minedTransactions", {"addresses": [{"to": "0xb87a436B93fFE9D75c5cFA7bAcFff96430b09868"}], "includeRemoved": false, "hashesOnly": false}]}'
```

The websocket seems to work fine (receiving messages) for non-filtered subscriptions:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id": 2, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["alchemy_minedTransactions"]}
```

Using `wscat -c wss://arb-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/API_KEY` to subscribe. [API docs](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/alchemy-minedtransactions)

Anyone else seeing this issues or any ideas how to solve? Am I missing something in the filtered sub message or have the docs changed? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

All address chars need to be lowercase:

`0xb87a436B93fFE9D75c5cFA7bAcFff96430b09868` should be `0xb87a436b93ffe9d75c5cfa7bacfff96430b09868`